# Encryption in xampp (apache)

Tags: encryption, xampp, .htpasswd

What kind of encryption id used in xampp .htpasswd?

I typed

> (ramin)

for password and this is the result

> $apr1$ErR/ZCuV$KSauU1bX4U1fqO3x7tQYN/

Comment: what kind of encryption is used in xampp .htpasswd? I typed (ramin) for password and this is $apr1$ErR/ZCuV$KSauU1bX4U1fqO3x7tQYN/

Comment: Are you asking what kind of hashing scheme is used for htpasswd? Note hashing is not encryption, because encryption can be reversed and hashes cannot be unhashed. Also note that you can [edit] your question. You can also delete your comments.

Answer (score 0):

It is an encoded MD5 hash, Apache proprietary. There is some information [in the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html) but to really see what is going on you need [the source of apr_md5.c](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/apr/apr-util/branches/1.3.x/crypto/apr_md5.c?view=co).

Basically it starts with a *magic*: `$apr1$`. This is not to fool you, it probably stands for Apache Password Routine version 1 or something similar.

Then comes an encoded salt of 0..8 bytes (8 bytes being the default it seems). This is a base 64 encoding but it is not the regular base 64 encoding. It uses a different alphabet with a relatively strange ordering:

```
./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

This salt in turn is ended using a single `$` character.

The password hash is basically an (overly) complex calculation using MD5 and transposition in the end. The password strengthening is performed using a non-configurable 1000 iterations of MD5 within this calculation. The final result is 16 bytes of MD5, encoded using the base 64 encoding explained above.

You cannot retrieve the password from the hash. The only thing you can do is take the salt, guess a password and see if it correct (using the minimum of 1000 iterations). In the olden days 1000 MD5 iterations may have seemed a lot, but unfortunately that's not the case any longer. You are better off using the bcrypt alternative.